# add zero in numerictextbox field

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox, telerik, numeric-textbox

I have numeric text box like that

```
<telerik:radnumerictextbox showspinbuttons="true" incrementsettings-interceptarrowkeys="true" incrementsettings-interceptmousewheel="true" labelwidth="120px" runat="server" id="ddStartHour" width="100px" MaxLength="2" MaxValue="12" Value="0" MinValue="0" CssClass="app-input" DataType="System.Integer" >

    <NumberFormat  DecimalDigits="0" />

</telerik:radnumerictextbox>
```

Now my numbers can be 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12.

But I want to add zero before the numbers which number is less than 10. So I want to show my numbers like 00,01,02,03,04,05,06,07,08,09,10,11,12.

How can I do that?

THX.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can achieve this through the client side methods of the [RadNumericTextBox Client Object](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/input-client-side-radnumerictextbox.html), try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function formatValue(sender, args) {
    var intCurrentValue = sender.get_value();
    if (intCurrentValue < 10) {
        sender.set_textBoxValue("0"+intCurrentValue);
    }
}
</script>
<telerik:radnumerictextbox showspinbuttons="true" incrementsettings-interceptarrowkeys="true" incrementsettings-interceptmousewheel="true" labelwidth="120px" runat="server" id="ddStartHour" width="100px" MaxLength="2" MaxValue="12" Value="00" MinValue="0" CssClass="app-input" DataType="System.Integer" >
    <ClientEvents OnBlur="formatValue" OnLoad="formatValue" OnValueChanged="formatValue"  />
    <NumberFormat  DecimalDigits="0"  />
</telerik:radnumerictextbox>
```

In this example the formatValue method is called whenever the value is changed or the control lose focus, you can use the client side api of Telerik for a custom function since [formatting numeric values](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/input-numerictextbox-formatting-numeric-values.html) in telerik does not provide a way to format the value with a regular expression or so.

Answer (score 1):

In Kendo Please add the Format "0#".